# How to use @ to reference site metadata with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, metadata

I have some metadata in my Jekyll configuration in `_data/people.yml`; i.e.,

```
Costanza:
  firstname: George
  lastname: Costanza
Kramer:
  firstname: Cosmo
  lastname: Kramer
```

I often refer to those people in my posts. I'd like to just say something like `@Kramer` and have that rendered as `Cosmo Kramer`.

- Is there a plugin to do this?
- If not, how hard would it be to make one? I'm a decent programmer, but I haven't done ruby or really any web-based programming.

Comment: A plugin needs to be a tag `{% tag %}` or a filter `{{ sth | filter }}`. Just parsing for all @ needs more effort

Comment: There is a plug-In on GitHub [jekyll-mentions](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-mentions) maybe a beginning ...